# calculate min and max use for loops in R

Tags: r

i want to make a program which calculates  min and max of a vector using for loops , here is my code

```
d <- c(34,67,123,554,76)
m<-0
e<-0
for(i in d)  { if(d>i) { m<-d[i]
  print("max") 
} else if (d>i) { e<-d[i]
  print("min")
}}
```

and gives me 
[1] "max"
...

what's wrong ?

Comment: you are aware that `min(d)` and `max(d)` would give you the answer directly without loops, right?

Comment: Yes , i want to make this program instead of using min() and max()

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Why don't you try to explain the logic behind your code? It's useful to do that before actually implementing it in a code. For instance, what's the purpose of `if(d>i)`? And what about `m<-c[i]`? Who's `c`, since it's not defined anywhere?

Comment: Replace `d` inside the forloop, to `m` and `e`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/228487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all()` to test the vector `d` against a single element of it:

```
d <- c(34,67,123,554,76)
m<-0
e<-0
for(i in d){
  if(all(d <= i)){ 
    m <- i
    print(paste0("max = ", m))
}else if(all(d >= i)) { 
  e <- i
  print(paste0("min = ", e))
}}

[1] "min = 34"
[1] "max = 554"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error/warning, you need to compare `m` and `e` to `i` not to full vector `d`.

Something like this:

```
# example input
d <- c(34,67,123,554,76)

foo <- function(x){
  # some checks for input x
  # ...

  myMin <- x[1] 
  myMax <- x[1] 

  for(i in x[-1])  {
    if(i < myMin) { myMin <- i}
    if(i > myMax) { myMax <- i}
  }  
  # return
  c(Min = myMin, Max = myMax)
}

foo(d)
# Min Max 
#  34 554
```